# Driver not found Exception in Web Service example

Tags: eclipse, web-services

Hi
I am creating a web service and web service client in Eclipse IDE.
From the client I am able to access the methods of the web service, but when I write some code related to database( in the method of web service), I get Error that It is unable to locate the driver, But I have set the related jar file in the class path of the web service project.

After the above error I get the following Error:

```
[INFO] Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://localhost:5050/NewOracleMod1/services/Account.AccountHttpSoap11Endpoint/]
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:140)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:125)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:557)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:199)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:438)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at package1.AccountStub.updateAccount(AccountStub.java:202)
    at package1.TestClient11.main(TestClient11.java:14)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection refused: connect
```

I am new to Web services as well as to Eclipse IDE.
Please help me to come out of this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to put the jars in the lib of the project too. and the problem is solved